# How to reshape dataframe after using pandas pivot table?

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe :

```
Date_Range | Agent | Team | Dial | OCC 
15thNov     | x | L1 | 1 | 0
15th Nov | y | L1  | 1 | 1
30th Dec | z | L2 | 1 | 1
30th Dec | z | L1 | 1 | 1
15th Nov | y | L2  | 1 | 1
```

Date Range = either 15th Nov or 30th Nov , they are string values made from another column
I do the following

```
pd.pivot_table(df2, values=['dial','OCC'], index=['Team','agent'], columns='Date_Range', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

Expected Dataframe

```
           15th Nov          30th Dec
           Dial    OCC       Dial    0CC
Team Agent
L1    x      4       2        3        1
```

How do I achieve this?

Do I get this from using pandas groupby? Please help

Comment: Do you just want to have agent x? How are the values in your expected output computed?

Comment: no i want all agents team wise.. and SUM is the function in my expected output.. sum of connects and OCC each agent of a team made.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
pd.pivot_table(
    df2, values=['Dial','OCC'],
                   index=['Team','Agent'],
                   columns=['Date_Range'], aggfunc='sum')\
    .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)\
        .sort_index(axis=1)

Out[670]:
Date_Range     15th Nov      30th Dec     
               Dial  OCC     Dial  OCC
Team Agent                            
L1   x          1.0  0.0      NaN  NaN
     y          1.0  1.0      NaN  NaN
     z          NaN  NaN      1.0  1.0
L2   y          1.0  1.0      NaN  NaN
     z          NaN  NaN      1.0  1.0
```